# An abstract noun beginning with 'T' meaning originality/uniqueness?

Tags: single-word-requests, abstract-nouns

I tried to recall a fabulous word my A-Level English teacher shared with me a few months ago, but can't remember it for the life of me!

It:

- Was English (duh)
- Began with the letter 'T'
- Was a synonym for originality/uniqueness
- Was used in the context of telling another student to include some extra flair/spice/pizzazz in their work:

> To make that better you should include some {t???} next time.

Cheers to anyone who can think of it!

Comment: I've heard the phrase "put your thumbprint on it," used in this way.

Comment: Temperament?  I could see a music teacher using this.  *You have the notes.  Now add some temperament.*

Comment: @aparente001 Your comment made me think of *timbre*. I posted an answer with an acknowledgement.

Comment: How many letters?  Crosswords are not within the scope of this site.  Can you include any research from a dictionary or thesaurus?

Comment: It is not a crossword question based on the details. The OP is trying to remember a word and added all the relevant SWR details. Also, this is not answerable from a thesaurus search. For example, I've checked some thesauri for originality/uniqueness and there wasn't a match, plus the example/context provided has a nuance.

Answer (score 1):

Was it **timbre**?

It is a musical term meaning a quality that is distinct from pitch, intensity. So we could sing the exact same note with perfect pitch but there is “something else” that makes one irresistible and one blah.

As I said it’s a musical term, but I could see someone using it metaphorically because it is that something else, secret sauce, special quality, etc.

(Credit to a comment by @aprente001 for mentioning a musical term, which rang a bell in my head.)

Comment: Good answer. It is used figuratively also. Actually, I've thought about _timbre_ too but it doesnt't fit to the example/context. You don't add/include timbre; it is already part of someone/something, like a moral timbre. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: I don't buy it.  In music we could give something a *different* timbre.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the teacher used the word absolutely correctly or that the OP remembers correctly. While technically all acoustics have timbre, it could be bland. Someone already using the word figuratively could be off a little. It’s like saying food lacks flavor. (almost) Everything edible has flavor. It might be mild or bland, but it has flavor, but people say “this needs flavor.” I’m not wed to this answer; the OP is a “guess what I’m [my teacher is] thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *tint*. It is used figuratively as an allusion to its primary meaning: a colour, hue, usually slight or delicate; a tinge.<sup>[OED]</sup>

> tint, *n.* 
> *figurative* in various senses; *esp.* Quality, character, kind; a slight imparted or modifying character, a ‘tinge’ of something. 
> *His virtue was of the purest tint.* 
> *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202313?rskey=1pteCg&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)*

*Tinge* also has a similar figurative usage but *tint* is better for your example sentence:

> tinge, *n.* 
> *figurative.* A trace of a feeling or quality. - *OED*

Answer (score -3):

It is possible that the word you are looking for is tenacious.

i.e.) Jack Black's legendary band Tenacious D. Known for the song Kickapoo.

Comment: You do realize that in your example sentence the word 'tenacious' is part of the band's name?